# what is the purpose of using ":" in OCaml function declaration

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

What is actually meant by the OCaml statement?

```
let func (v: A.a) : unit =    

#rest of the function
```

1. does it mean it takes v of type A.a and return unit
2. or it takes two parameters, v and A.a and return a unit?
3. or it takes a function v with parameter A.a and returns a unit?
4. or something else?

Comment: I expected this to be explained at the very beginning of the OCaml manual, but I can't find a word about it.

Comment: yeah, that's why i posted here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let func (v: A.a) : unit =`

The first `:` means `v is a parameter and its type is expected to be A.a`.

The second `:` means `func is expected to return a type of unit`

Answer (score 2):

1 and maybe 3. In OCaml functions are values and if `A.a` is function-type your 1st argument of `func` is function.

Comment: so the :unit here is the return type? or unit is the type of the whole (v: A.a) statement?

Comment: yeah, last `: something` without parenthesis is return type for whole function.

Answer (score 2):

It means 1.

That is, if `v` has type `A.a`, then `func v` has type `unit`.
Or, equivalently, the type of `func` is `A.a -> unit`.